# Recreate Sitecore site locally from an existing site

Tags: migration, sitecore

I am supposed to recreate a sitecore site locally on my machine to match the client site. The client sent me three directories: Sitecore Foundation, Sitecore feature, and the website project. Each directory has it's own VS solution file and all three of them are MVC projects. I am confused as to how to upload those to my Sitecore instance that I installed. The idea is to get it working on my local machine so I can edit the site and publish. Is there anything else that I need to ask the client to send me in order to set it up locally? Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

In the easiest scenario you need code of the application and Sitecore items.

From what you wrote, you've got the code.

Now you need to install clean Sitecore instance (using exactly the same version as is used on the client site), compile your code and push the code to the `Website` folder of your Sitecore installation (e.g. using publish to folder option fro Visual Studio).

You also need Sitecore items. There are multiple options to install them in your local environment, e.g.:

- get the backup of Sitecore databases from your client and restore them in your local environment
- get Sitecore content packages with all the necessary items and install them in your local databases overriding items from clean Sitecore install
- get serialized items (either serialized with default Sitecore serialization mechanism, Unicorn or TDS) and restore them in your local environment.

Those are all the steps required in the simple scenario. There may be other steps needed if solution is more complicated but no one will be able to tell you what you need if they don't know the project.